# C Reading data from one file and writing it into another file

Tags: c, file-io

### The Problem:

I have a project I'm working on that works with Binary Search Trees and file input/output. The binary search tree seems to functioning properly, however one of the requirements is to be able to add data to the binary tree via input from a file (And later output all the binary tree data). I used the fgets+sscanf method to look through the file, and it appears that it grabs all the items correctly, but the strings get drastically altered. I suspect it to be a null terminator issue but cannot pinpoint where exactly I could fix it at. When I add nodes to the binary tree manually (not from the file), they are added without issue, and are written to a new text file without issue. The only issue comes from reading the data from a file, which is throwing some odd errors that modify my data (E.G. strings appear in weird formats like é@—Ç as opposed to the expected output of FirstName1 LastName1).

Also would like to apologize, I am still fairly new to C. So it may appear a little messy.

---

### My (futile) attempts:

As noted in the code below, I attempted manually adding null terminators to the strings since I believed that to be the issue. I've attempted changing the file contents and adding null terminators there, and I've tried using fscanf method of reading the file instead as well. I researched other stackoverflow pages searching for something I might be missing, but I haven't found anything. I'm sure it's something silly that I've overlooked.

---

### My text files:

Again, these below text file contents are only concerning from what is added from the file. Anything I manually add by calling the addNode function with string literals works without problem

My 'input' text file that I tried adding students from (aka that addFile uses in my tests):

```
400085 FirstName1 LastName1 3.88 CompSci
400076 FirstName2 LastName2 2.77 LibertyArts
```

My 'output' text file that writeFile uses:

```
400085  é@—Ç 3.880000 ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ 
400076  é@—Ç 2.770000 ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```

---

### The Code:

**addFile**
Takes a string name, finds the file, and opens its contents

```
void addFile(char* name) {
    FILE* myFile = fopen(name, "r");
    if (myFile == NULL) {
        perror(name);
        return;
    }
    int tempId = 0;
    char firstName[100];
    char lastName[100];
    double GPA = 0.0;
    char major[100];
    int res = 0;
    char line[10000];

    while (fgets(line, 1000, myFile) != NULL) {
        res = sscanf(line, "%d %s %s %lf %s", &tempId, firstName, lastName, &GPA, major);
        firstName[99] = '\0';
        lastName[99] = '\0';
        major[99] = '\0';
        addNode(tempId, firstName, lastName, GPA, major);
    }

    fclose(myFile);
}
```

**WriteFile**
Writes into the text file, testFile.txt the contents of the binary search tree

```
void preorder(struct Node* nodeAt) {
    char buffer[10000];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d %s %s %lf %s \n", nodeAt->id, nodeAt->firstName, nodeAt->lastName, nodeAt->GPA, nodeAt->major);
    strcat(tempString, buffer);
    if (nodeAt->leftChild != NULL)
        preorder(nodeAt->leftChild);
    if (nodeAt->rightChild != NULL)
        preorder(nodeAt->rightChild);
}

void writeFile() {
    FILE* fp = fopen("testFile.txt", "w");
    tempString = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10000);
    preorder(root);
    fprintf(fp, "%s", tempString);
    free(tempString);
    tempString = "";
}
```

**Other related functions that addFile calls**

```
/*
createNode() method
"safe" way of creating the node. Also cleans up the code.
*/
struct Node* createNode(int id, char* firstName, char* lastName, double GPA, char* major) {
    struct Node* myNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    if (myNode != NULL) {
        myNode->id = id;
        myNode->firstName = firstName;
        myNode->lastName = lastName;
        myNode->GPA = GPA;
        myNode->major = major;
        myNode->rightChild = NULL;
        myNode->leftChild = NULL;
        myNode->parent = NULL;
        return myNode;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}

/*
addNode() + addNodeHelper() methods
Adds a node to the binary tree. The helper method is just recursive to make searching easier
*/
struct Node* addNodeHelper(struct Node* nodeAt, int id, struct Node* nodeToAdd) {
    struct Node* temp = nodeAt;

    if (temp->leftChild == NULL && id < temp->id) {
        nodeAt->leftChild = nodeToAdd;
        nodeAt->leftChild->parent = nodeAt;
    }
    else if (temp->rightChild == NULL && id > temp->id) {
        nodeAt->rightChild = nodeToAdd;
        nodeAt->rightChild->parent = nodeAt;
    }

    if (id < temp->id)
        addNodeHelper(temp->leftChild, id, nodeToAdd);
    else if (id > temp->id)
        addNodeHelper(temp->rightChild, id, nodeToAdd);
}

void addNode(int id, char* firstName, char* lastName, double GPA, char* major) {
    struct Node* myNode = createNode(id, firstName, lastName, GPA, major);
    if (myNode != NULL) {
        struct Node* findTheNode = findNode(root, myNode->id);
        if (root == NULL) {
            root = myNode;
            return;
        }
        if (findTheNode != NULL) {
            printf("ERROR: Student ID must be unique!\n");
            return;
        } else
            addNodeHelper(root, myNode->id, myNode);
    }
}
```

Any hints/recommendations are much appreciated :)

Comment: `fopen` can fail for many reasons.  Let the system tell you why it failed.  `FILE* myFile = fopen(name, "r"); if ( myFile == NULL ) {perror(name) ...`

Comment: We need to see `createNode`. I suspect it's not making copies of the strings when it puts them into the `Node` structure, so you're saving pointers to local strings.

Comment: @Barmar -- Edited to show createNode

Comment: @WilliamPursell Dully noted - Thanks! :). Modified with perror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createNode` is just saving pointers to the strings that it's given. `addFile` overwrites the same strings each time through the loop, so every node has the same pointers. Also, these are local variables, so the pointers become invalid after `addFile` returns.

You need to make copies of the strings.

```
        addNode(tempId, strdup(firstName), strdup(lastName), GPA, strdup(major));
```

Comment: WOW... All those hours spent debugging for it to be as simple as a one line fix. Your timely manner of responding is much appreciated. Thank you so much!